# OpenLayers: How can I stop the click selection from passing through a higher layer?

Tags: openlayers

If I click on the green rectangle, which is on a layer with a zindex of 4 in the smallVectorLayer, it is not selected because I have set the Select layers to `layers: [vectorLayer]`. vectorLayer is where the two red rectangles are located and it has a zindex of 3.

It is good that the green rectangle is not selected.

The problem is that the red rectangle under the green one is selected.

The selection process should have stopped at the green rectangle because that is where the click happened. Instead, the selection process continues to the lower layer.

What do I need to change so the red rectangle underneath the green one is not selected when the green rectangle is clicked?

```js
function createRectangle(polygons) {
  const features = [];

  for (const [i, polygon] of polygons.entries()) {
    const feature = {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: polygon
      },
      properties: {
        id: i
      }
    };

    features.push(feature);
  }

  const json = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features
  };

  return json;
}

const bigRectangle = createRectangle([
  [
    [
      [40, 30],
      [40, 35],
      [70, 35],
      [70, 30]
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      [40, 20],
      [40, 25],
      [70, 25],
      [70, 20]
    ]
  ]
]);

const styles = {
  Polygon: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: "hsla(0, 50%, 100%, 1.0)",
      width: 5
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: "hsla(0, 50%, 50%, 0.3)"
    })
  })
};

const styleFunction = function (feature) {
  const featureType = feature.getGeometry().getType();
  return styles[featureType];
};

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    featureProjection: "EPSG:4326" // 4326 3857
  }).readFeatures(bigRectangle)
});

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: styleFunction,
  zindex: 3
});

const smallRectangle = createRectangle([
  [
    [
      [53, 31],
      [53, 34],
      [57, 34],
      [57, 31]
    ]
  ]
]);

const smallStyles = {
  Polygon: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: "hsla(120, 50%, 100%, 1.0)",
      width: 5
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: "hsla(120, 50%, 50%, 0.3)"
    })
  })
};

const smallStyleFunction = function (feature) {
  const featureType = feature.getGeometry().getType();
  return smallStyles[featureType];
};

const smallVectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    featureProjection: "EPSG:4326" // 4326 3857
  }).readFeatures(smallRectangle)
});

const smallVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: smallVectorSource,
  style: smallStyleFunction,
  zindex: 4
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer,
    smallVectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: [55, 25],
    zoom: 5
  })
});

const selected = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: "hsla(270, 50%, 50%, .1)"
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: "hsla(270, 50%, 50%, 1)",
    width: 5
  })
});

function selectStyle(feature) {
  const color = feature.get("COLOR") || "hsla(270, 50%, 50%, .1)";
  selected.getFill().setColor(color);
  return selected;
}

const selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
  style: selectStyle,
  layers: [vectorLayer]
});

selectSingleClick.on("select", function (e) {
  console.log("select event",);
});


map.addInteraction(selectSingleClick);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 512px;
  width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom condition which checks if there are features in other layers

```js
function createRectangle(polygons) {
  const features = [];

  for (const [i, polygon] of polygons.entries()) {
    const feature = {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: polygon
      },
      properties: {
        id: i
      }
    };

    features.push(feature);
  }

  const json = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features
  };

  return json;
}

const bigRectangle = createRectangle([
  [
    [
      [40, 30],
      [40, 35],
      [70, 35],
      [70, 30]
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      [40, 20],
      [40, 25],
      [70, 25],
      [70, 20]
    ]
  ]
]);

const styles = {
  Polygon: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: "hsla(0, 50%, 100%, 1.0)",
      width: 5
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: "hsla(0, 50%, 50%, 0.3)"
    })
  })
};

const styleFunction = function (feature) {
  const featureType = feature.getGeometry().getType();
  return styles[featureType];
};

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    featureProjection: "EPSG:4326" // 4326 3857
  }).readFeatures(bigRectangle)
});

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: styleFunction,
  zindex: 3
});

const smallRectangle = createRectangle([
  [
    [
      [53, 31],
      [53, 34],
      [57, 34],
      [57, 31]
    ]
  ]
]);

const smallStyles = {
  Polygon: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: "hsla(120, 50%, 100%, 1.0)",
      width: 5
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: "hsla(120, 50%, 50%, 0.3)"
    })
  })
};

const smallStyleFunction = function (feature) {
  const featureType = feature.getGeometry().getType();
  return smallStyles[featureType];
};

const smallVectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    featureProjection: "EPSG:4326" // 4326 3857
  }).readFeatures(smallRectangle)
});

const smallVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: smallVectorSource,
  style: smallStyleFunction,
  zindex: 4
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer,
    smallVectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: "EPSG:4326",
    center: [55, 25],
    zoom: 5
  })
});

const selected = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: "hsla(270, 50%, 50%, .1)"
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: "hsla(270, 50%, 50%, 1)",
    width: 5
  })
});

function selectStyle(feature) {
  const color = feature.get("COLOR") || "hsla(270, 50%, 50%, .1)";
  selected.getFill().setColor(color);
  return selected;
}

const selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: function(e) {
    return ol.events.condition.singleClick(e) &&
    map.getFeaturesAtPixel(e.pixel, {
      layerFilter: function(l) {
        //return l !== vectorLayer;
        return l.getZIndex() > vectorLayer.getZIndex()
      }
    }).length === 0
  },
  style: selectStyle,
  layers: [vectorLayer]
});

selectSingleClick.on("select", function (e) {
  console.log("select event",);
});


map.addInteraction(selectSingleClick);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 512px;
  width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/7.1.0/dist/ol.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

The Select interaction will select the top feature in the layer.  You can test that here https://codesandbox.io/s/translate-features-forked-vtcigv  Select a state and drag it above or below another when zIndex is in alphabetic order of state names.  Then click on empty are and then on the overlap.  Change `style.setZIndex(Number(feature.get('name').charCodeAt(0)));` to `style.setZIndex(100 - Number(feature.get('name').charCodeAt(0)));` to make sure zIndex really is being used.  So you only need to bother with the zIndex of layers.  If you have multiple layers with unique zIndex just change `return l !== vectorLayer` in my example to `return l.getZIndex() > vectorLayer.getZIndex()`

Comment: Thank you. I was headed down that route, but had missed that getFeaturesAtPixel can take a layer filter. That insight makes the procedure easier.

Comment: Playing around with this a bit more, I noticed there is still a bit more work to be done. If the red rectangle was above the green one, then it should be selected if the click was in the same area as the green rectangle. The code as written will not select the red rectangle. Extra checking on the zIndex of the layers is needed and, to be complete, the ordering of features in the same layer needs to be considered to handle cases of overlap. The layer function getFeatures looks useful as it will return the topmost feature that intersects the given pixel.

Comment: The only thing I can think of to do at this point is when I am adding features to the source, set a property on each feature so I can know what layer is belongs to. Do you know if map.getFeaturesAtPixel will return those features in order of top most to bottom most, taking into account overlap when two features are in the same layer? I am thinking there is a better way to manage this. If you have any further advice, I am interested.

Comment: I have updated the answer to handle multiple layers with unique zIndex

Comment: Confirmed. That works well.